# Importing variables from another Python script

Tags: python

Is it possible to import a Python script into a main script and then just use the variables? I don't want the other script to execute inside of the main script, just attach one of the variables...

Comment: `from script import var`

Comment: Importing another script executes it. Whether than has unwanted effects depends on how the script is written (whether it uses an `if __name__=='__main__'` block appropriately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit the script being imported, there's a solution:

Put all the executed code into a block starting with

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

In this way, the code in the `if` block above will be executed only if the script is run directly. i.e. when you run `python script.py`.

You can import only the variable like this:

```
from script import var
```

If you want to `import` the variable without going through the whole script, then as per Python's design it's not possible. `import` will always go through the whole script being imported, and will avoid whatever that's inside `__name__ == '__main__'`.

You have an option to read the script file and find the variables, then do it yourself by parsing and executing it, but IMO that's unnecessary job to do since you have `import`.

You can see the answers under [Python: import module without executing script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16177238/5958455)